# TCP Server having Five clients and one of client has closed abnormally

Tags: tcpserver

TCP server is having connections with 5 clients and its waiting on select call for clients to read\write.

But one of the client got closed abnormally.
How Server will come to know that client got closed.

Comment: A `TcpClient` can only handle one connection at a time. You'd have to create an array or list of clients if you are to connect five of them. Also, without showing your code there isn't much we can do...

Answer (score 0):

Is your server configured to handle multiple clients in the same time ?
For example, does it create a sub process every time a new client comes ?

If it is indeed a multiple clients TCP server, you can make the sub process send a message to the main process with the signal() system call when it disconnect : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/signal.htm